# Definir placeholder com variável PHP

Tags: php, placeholder, echo

Tenho um Formulário de Cadastro/pesquisa e agora estou adicionando a opção para editar os campos. Para o funcionário não ficar confuso, eu queria definir o placeholder com uma variável PHP, através do `echo`. É possível fazer isso?

```php
<div class="inputs">
    <?php if ($id != '') { ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />ID: <?php echo $id; ?>
    <?php } ?> 
    <?php echo $cliente; ?>
    <input type="text" name="cliente" maxlength="50" placeholder="<?php echo $cliente; ?>" value="<?php echo $cliente; ?>"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="produto" maxlength="25" placeholder="PRODUTO" value="<?php echo $produto; ?>"/><br>
    <input type="text" name="solicitante" maxlength="50" placeholder="SOLICITANTE" value="<?php echo $solicitante; ?>"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="status" maxlength="25" placeholder="STATUS" value="<?php echo $status; ?>"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="incluiu" maxlength="25" placeholder="INCLUIU" value="<?php echo $incluiu; ?>"/><br/>
    <input id="submit" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Cadastrar" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thiago a pergunta está pouco clara... Quer fazer isso em PHP para ser aplicado a um elemento HTML? Que tipo de elemento é? um input? Pode juntar um exemplo do código que tem e como quer que seja apresentado ao funcionário

Comment: Você quer setar ou pegar o placeholder?

Comment: Perdão pela pergunta pouco clara, atualizei a pergunta com meu código, tentei dar echo no placeholder mas ele saiu em branco.

Comment: Earendul, buscar no meu banco.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado a todas as respostas ;)

Comment: Se o que você quer é um jeito de resetar o valor para um valor anterior, o caminho é usar o campo _value_ e o método _reset_ do form, ou um _data-parameter_. (ou até _labels_ mesmo)

Comment: eu entendi, eu perguntei se era possível fazer isso e a resposta foi sim. grato a todos pelas respostas.

Answer (score 6):

É possível sim:

```
<input type="text" placehold="<?php  echo 'palavra'; ?>" />
```

Comment: já tentei dessa forma e resultado vem em branco.

Comment: Provavelmente a variável `$cliente` está vindo em branco. O `value` também está em branco?

Comment: Não, o value está correto.

Answer (score 3):

Só faz sentido usar isto se a variável for diferente do campo, pois o *placeholder* só aparece com campo vazio. E do jeito que você está fazendo, o *placeholder* só vai ser usado vazio mesmo. Provavelmente teria que ser feito algo neste sentido:

```
<input type="text" name="cliente" maxlength="50" placeholder="<?php echo 'CLIENTE'; ?>"
   value="<?php echo $cliente; ?>"/><br/>
```

Ou mesmo assim:

```
$pla_cliente = 'Cliente';
... seu código PHP ...

<input type="text" name="cliente" maxlength="50" placeholder="<?php echo $pla_cliente; ?>"
   value="<?php echo $cliente; ?>"/><br/>
```

mas sempre usando variáveis diferentes para o *placeholder* e para o campo.

**Se você estiver tentando usar o valor para um *reset* dos campos, basta usar o *reset* do próprio *form* para voltar o valor anterior**

Comment: Não necessariamente.
Vai que ele quer deixar o placeholder sendo o nome do usuário, pra ficar fácil dele entender caso ele apague ou queira trocar o valor. O problema, é que ele não deixou muito claro o objetivo dele, assim não teria como darmos um exemplo bem feito.

Comment: Eu quero fazer um UPDATE no banco e quero que placeholder seja o valor que eu pretendo mudar.

Comment: @Thiago nao tem problema de onde você vai pegar o placeholder. Só não pode ser o mesmo valor do campo, senão não faz o mínimo sentido.

Comment: Rodrigo Coelho, Exatamente isso.

Comment: Thiago, o placeholder é apenas uma exibição para o usuário identificar o que pode ser digitado no campo. Ele não vai influenciar em nada no POST do formulário.

Comment: Então não é possível eu resgatar o valor anterior?

Comment: O placeholder é o valor de exibição quando o campo está vazio, nada mais nada menos. Se quiser usar o valor pra um reset do form, ou use o value, ou use um data-parameter customizado.

Comment: Tenho um formulário que foi preenchido por um usuário, eventualmente, é preciso fazer certas alterações nesse formulário, isso já está feito. funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Oque eu quero fazer agora é o seguinte:
Mostrar o valor no placeholder somente mostrar, ele não vai ter função alguma, só preciso que seja exatamente o mesmo dado que está no meu banco.

Answer (score 1):

Com JavaScript podes fazer assim:

```js
var placeholder = document.getElementById("entrada").getAttribute("placeholder");
alert(placeholder);
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="teste" id="entrada">
```

Comment: Ainda assim vem em branco.

Answer (score 1):

A Alteração que sugiro é a seguinte:

```
<input type="text" name="cliente" maxlength="50" placeholder="<?php echo $cliente; ?>" value="<?php echo $cliente; ?>"/><br/>
```

Perceba que você está **setando o placeholder** e depois substituindo pelo **value**

no caso remova o value e veŕá que o placeholder está funcionando conrretamente.

```
<input type="text" name="cliente" maxlength="50" placeholder="<?=
$cliente; ?>"/><br/>
```